# Custom template fetching with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am reading about AngularJS (but not yet using it) and I cannot seem to find the following information.
For example I have

`<ng-include src="templateName.tpl"></ng-include>`

I believe AngularJS will simply  do a HTML request to fetch the templateName.tpl.

How do I force AngularJS to call a custom provider function instead, which could look like this:

```
function myTemplateProvider(templateUrl, locals, callback) {
   getTemplateAsynchronously(templateUrl, function(compiledTemplate) {
       callback(compiledTemplate, locals);
   });
}
```

I am seeking cutting all HTTP request after initial page load. Why? Because it should be possible.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Might wanna look at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache

Comment: read the docs about templates. Can be in script tags, or strings stored in modules and added to `$templateCache` or they can be pulled from url using ajax. ...angular is very flexible. Also... it checks availability prior to making any ajax call internally

Comment: $templateCache sounds interesting, gotta investigate that but it will not provide a lazy fetching mechanism. I am striving to have HTTP downloadable templates in the debug phase and in production compile all templates to javascript (then the $templateCache could help). What do you guys think about this https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/3vTOCISR4wY/0cl07wfaniYJ ? Is that valid or too hackish?

Comment: you could lazy load templates into cache.